# How can I find out if Debian 8.6.0 is safe to install and compatible with my computer?

Tags: linux, laptop, debian, hp-pavilion, debian-jessie

I currently have `Windows 10` installed on my `HP Pavilion x360 13`.

I have recently come to the decision that there is no reason for me to use Windows as I only use it to browse the web and write some code, every now and then, on Debian 8.6.0 (Jessie) which is installed inside a Virtual-Box.

I would like to install Debian on my laptop and replace Windows.
Before I go ahead and install Debian I would like to know if there are any known problems when it comes to Debian on my Laptop.
I've been looking around on Google but cannot find anything.

Here is some more information:

- I can go back to Windows 8.1 and upgrade to windows 10 if I have to (I probably won't)
- All of my data is backed up and safe
- I am installing Debian from a Sandisk USB
- I plan to install Debian 8.6.0 on a HP Pavilion x360 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When researching compatibility with Linux, don't look for computer model - this is usually useless since same model might be sold in many configurations. Instead break it down to key components. That is where the issues might appear:

1. Graphics card. Do you have dedicated graphics card (Nvidia, Ati)? Look up the model. The drivers might not fully support it and you could have lower performance.
2. Wireless adapter. Look up if anyone has unsolved problems with your model, or with bluetooth.
3. Special hardware you plan to utilize (fingerprint reader, gyroscope).

Linux is compatible with most of hardware, probably a lot more than Windows is. There shouldn't be any issues that couldn't be solved by upgrading to newer Debian version (testing).

Comment: Thank you for the information, I've been researching all day and once again found nothing. I think its safe to assume that there are no major issues with Debian at the moment, but once again, thank you for your time and help, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Mango, This is right.  The issues are with availability of drivers.  If you are going with Debian, you need to get the "non-free" distro.  Debian is a stickler for open source, and many drivers are not.  They make those available in the non-free DVD (it's no cost, non-free refers to non-open-source).

Comment: @Mango you're welcome. The general rule of thumb is - the more widespread the hardware is, the more likely it will work well in linux. So I'd be careful around features like automatically rotating screens, multiple build-in graphics cards and similar things that appear on few computer models only.